# Calling a Javascript function from an applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet

All I want to do is call a javascript function from a Applet and pass multiple variables, I'm able to do this with just one variable, but I want to do it with multiple.

calling Javascript function from applet and passing one variable which works:

```
  msg = "test";
    try {
        getAppletContext().showDocument
                (new URL("javascript:UpdateComputerDetails(\"" + msg + "\")"));
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException me) { }
```

How Can I pass Multiple variables to this function?

Comment: What have you tried so far in passing two variables instead of one? I fail to understand what's blocking you there... you have all you need.

Comment: Yes I have tried to pass two variables but I'm fighting syntax, this is  what I'm trying to do: (new URL("javascript:UpdateComputerDetails(\"" + msg + "\","" + msg2 + ")"));

Comment: Try it as `(new URL("javascript:UpdateComputerDetails('" + msg + "','" + msg2 + "')"));`

Comment: Also change `catch (MalformedURLException me) { }` to `catch (MalformedURLException me) { me.printStackTrace(); }` and copy/paste the output as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's the liveconnect package but I don't know how well it does cross-browser:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html

Comment: I just wanted to change the code I had as it works, it just needs altering slightly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll simply want to use:

```
arg1 = "foo";
arg2 = "bar";
try {
    getAppletContext().showDocument
            (new URL("javascript:UpdateComputerDetails(\"" + arg1 + "\", \"" + arg2 + "\")"));
}
catch (MalformedURLException me) { }
```

The tough part to master is actually building the URL, since you'll have to escape some stuff in one way or another. You can ease the pain by using single-quotes in the JS:

```
"javascript:UpdateComputerDetails('" + arg1 + "', '" + arg2 + "')"
```

Now, you need to be careful that `arg1` and `arg2` (and if you go for more, the other arguments as well) either do not contain `'` (or `"` if you use the double-quote syntax), or these are properly escaped before you build your URL.

Comment: Thanks Romain for explaining it.